# Accessing file in my directory using where one file is working good but other one is not being imported(?)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, directory

I am trying to access a file, `Maxoflist.py` in a directory using vs-code. I expect the maximum value in the list to be printed, but it is not. No error occurs, and functions defined in another file, `shipping.py`, work fine.

```
import shipping
import Maxoflist #imported the entire module shippinng
shipping.calc_shipping() #working good
findmaxoflist() #not working
```

`Maxoflist.py`:

```
def findmaxoflist():
    Items = [5,61,7,2,4,9,1]
    Max = Items[0]
    for num in Items:
        if Max < num:
            Max   = num

    print(f"Maximum Number is: {Max}")

findmaxoflist()
```

`shipping.py`:

```
def calc_shipping():    #working good when imported
    print("Callin the calculate shipping")
```

Comment: findmaxoflist should be called this way "Maxoflist.findmaxoflist()" like you do with another one. P.S. it also says "improt Maxoflist", consider changing that to import :)

Comment: Still Not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the file in that directory is not missing/deleted or the name is correctly spelled!

Try this:

```py
from Maxoflist import findmaxoflist
```